# How to multiply correctly two numbers in a method?

Tags: c#, methods

```
{
    Console.ForegroundColor= ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name and I will tell you how many letters your name has!");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Count(name);
    Console.WriteLine("Now tell me two numbers and I will multiply them!");
    Console.Read();

    try
    {
        Multiply();
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a number!");
    }
}

public static void Count(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your name has {0} letters!", name.Length);
}

public static void Multiply()
{

    string firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
    string secondNum = Console.ReadLine();
    int num = Int32.Parse(firstNum);
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(secondNum);
    int result = num * num1;
    Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", result);
}
```

Im a beginner and Im learning about methods so I made this simple code where the user should enter two numbers and I should multiply them, the problem is, whenever I enter two random numbers, I am getting some completely different numbers back no matter if i want to add them, multiply them or something third.

I cannot figure out why the "num1 * num2;" is not giving me a correct number. E.G. 54*19 should give me 1026, but instead its giving me -15.

Comment: Read up (no pun intended) on the difference between `Console.Read` and `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, after removing the Console.Read now its working as it should! lmao! thanks

Comment: `Console.Read` only gets the next character from the input stream, not the whole line.

Comment: @DavidG: the `.Read()` will eat the first character intended for the `.ReadLine()`, and the end user is likely not aware of that effect.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, I assumed OP was using it as a "press any key to continue" input.

Answer (score 2):

you need to comment on the `Console.Read();` line. this is the main cause.

I have run your code by commenting on the above line and it works as expected for me

Also, you need to handle the scenarios when the user can enter a non-integer input, so you could use `int.TryParse` for the same.

Also, try to handle the scenario where the integer value is very large and the multiplication of two numbers exceeds the integer max value.